# Event pop-up is drawing behind calendar grid and numbers

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar version 3.9.0. We had previously been using a much older version.

For the events in the calendar, when you click them, it opens a pop-up window. This window is drawing behind the grid lines and numbers and it gets cut off if it goes beyond the bounds of the grid (for example opening an even right near the left edge would cause any of the popup that extends further left than the calendar to be cut off).

My calendar is defined like so:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

locale: initialLocaleCode,
height: "auto",
contentHeight: "auto",

header: {
    left: 'title',
    center: '',
    right: 'today prev,next'
},

loading: function(isLoading) {
    if (isLoading) {
        isCalClick = true;
    } else {
        isCalClick = false;
    }
},

events: function (start, end, timezone, callback) {
    $.ajax({
        url: homeUrl + 'Run',
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "JSON",

        success: function (result) {
            var events = [];

            $.each(result.Events, function (i, data) {
                events.push(
                    {
                        moduleId: data.moduleId,
                        title: data.title,
                        id: data.id,
                        timeStamp: data.timeStamp,
                        state: data.state,
                        user: data.user,
                        result: data.result,

                        start: moment(data.start).format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                        end: moment(data.timeStamp).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
                    });
            });

            callback(events);
        },
        error: function () {
            alert('there was an error while fetching events!');
        }
    });
}, 

eventRender: function (event, element) {
    createEvent(event, $(element));
}
});
```

Then there is a create popover event that creates popups (popovers) for each event...

```
    function createPopover(event, el) {

    var title = event.title;
    var html = SomeMethodToGetHtmlContentsOfPopup();

    el.popover({
        'placement': "left",
        'html': true,
        'title': title,
        'content': html,
    });
}
```

The popup (popover) window itself can be styled with the .popover CSS...

```
#calendar .popover,
.large-chart .popover {
color: #333;
width: 340px;
z-index: 999 !important;
position: relative !important;
}
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations of styling this .popover control. The styles do apply as I see them when debugging it. I would expect putting z-index higher than any other items and using position:relative should bring this to the front but it does not.

Any ideas? The examples I've seen running online don't seem to have this issue, just what I'm doing.

Comment: Add Runnable script to your question. It's not possible to read such a long code.

Comment: The longest block is 57 lines with lots of spaces, I would hardly say that's not possible to ready. I'm afraid this is the best I can do. Its not feasible to make this runnable without publishing my entire application or a ton of work pulling it out into its own thing..

Comment: I agree the code is not too large but equally you could very quickly make it runnable by referencing CDNs for the JS and CSS dependencies, and using some static event data, or pulling the event data from a mock endpoint e.g. an entry at myjson.com. But anyway, what are you using to make the popover? It's not a fullCalendar feature

Comment: createPopover is the code that creates the popover (the second code block above). It gets called within the createEvent event in the calendar definition. The div that gets created has the .popover class applied to it (which is my third block of code above). 

That's not a fullCalendar feature? It feels like it is.

Comment: Well you used the method, you should know how you came to be able to use it?? Perhaps you didn't write this page, which would explain why you wouldn't know? It's definitely not a fullCalendar feature. It's not documented anywhere in their API for a start. Probably you've got some other 3rd-party JS script in your page which is providing it. It would help to know what that is. BTW I only found your comment by chance coming back to this page. If you want people to respond, tag them in your comment with an @ followed by their username.